# Mockito spy functionality

Tags: java, mockito

I am testing some code which uses Mockito spy to monitor real objects.
For example, I created a Map & call size() method on it and verify that size() method was called.

I have following code:

```
Map<String, String> mapTest = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> spyMap = spy(mapTest);
mapTest.size();
verify(spyMap, times(1)).size();
```

When I run the test, I get an error that there was no interaction with size() method. If I call spyMap.size() then this test goes through fine.
What should I do to monitor 'mapTest'

Comment: `mapTest` isn't the spy, so why do you expect `size()` to have been called on the spy when you are calling it on a different object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the verify method in Mockito is to validate the MOCKED or PARTIALLY MOCKED object has something done with it.  You can't really monitor a real object that isn't created through Mockito.  You can however use a spy objects that have been created through Mockito.  Spies are are partial mocks.  The rest of the mock remains the same as the original.  The idea is that you then override the method you wish to stub out.  So in a sense if you don't override anything, you have a copy of the original object when you don't override any methods.  So to really test how many times the size method was called you can create a spy of the HashMap and then inject it and let your code work on it to see how many times it was called.  Often this forces us to refactor our code in order to make it testable.  You may need to find a way to inject the HashMap so the spy can be inserted and later on have an assert applied against it.